# APIからの値が0になるまでループさせたい

Tags: swift, swift2

## 実現したいこと

APIからのレスポンスとしてnumberが返ってきますがその値が0になるまで
Alamofireで同じAPIに対してリクエストを投げ続けたいのですが、
どのようにコーディングすれば良いのか思いつきません。

通信結果を投げた順番で結果を受け取るようにしたい場合、
どのように記述することで処理を実装できますか？

while文で囲った場合はレスポンスの速さ次第によっては、
受け取る順番がバラバラ担ってしまうと思うのですが、どうでしょうか。

---

## 対象のコード

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    /*ここの処理をループさせたいのです。*/
    getMessageList(apiResponse: { response in
        ※省略
    })
    /*--------------------------------*/
}

func getMessageList(apiResponse: (responseData: Int) -> ()) {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "(APIのURL)", headers: customHeader)
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard let object = response.result.value else {
                return
            }
            let json = JSON(object)
            let number: Int = json["result"]["number"].int!
            apiResponse(responseData: number)
    }

}
```

---

[teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/46880)にも投稿させていただいています。
至急と言うほどでは無いですが、早めに解答をいただけるとありがたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

teratailにて回答頂きました。

```
private var _response_numbers: Array<Int> = []
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        /*ここの処理をループさせたいのです。*/
        getMessageList()
        /*--------------------------------*/

}

func getMessageList() {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "(APIのURL)", headers: customHeader)
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard let object = response.result.value else {
                return
            }
            let json = JSON(object)
            let number: Int = json["result"]["number"].int!
            _response_numbers.append(number)
            if number != 0 {
              self.getMessageList()
            }
    }

}
```